# A relation involving many integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I need help to proof the following: Consider the multiple integrals below:

$$ \int_{a}^{b} dx_{1} \int_{a}^{b} dx_{2} \cdots \int_{a}^{b} dx_{n} \ f(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}).$$

Here, $f$ is a function that is unchanged if we exchange two of your variables, that is

$$f(..., x_{i}, ..., x_{j}, ...) = f(..., x_{j}, ..., x_{i}, ...).$$

I have to prove that this integral is equal to

$$n! \int_{a}^{b} dx_{1} \int_{a}^{x_{1}} dx_{2} \cdots \int_{a}^{x_{n-1}} dx_{n} \ f(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}).$$

It may look likes weird, but I am studying many-body perturbation theory using Feynman diagrams and this relation is very useful. I know that this is true, but I can't find anywhere a good proof or justification for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are integrating over the region where $ b \geq x_1 \geq x_2 \geq x_3 \geq \ldots \geq x_n \geq a $.

By the condition that the function is symmetric in the variables, it follows that this is $\frac{1}{n!}$ of the original integral. Hence the equality holds.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But could you explain with more details why this hold?

Comment: Do you understand what I'm saying? If yes, what are you stuck with?

Comment: Well, i think I understood... I can separete the integration region in many others regions, one in which I have $a < x_{1} < x_{2} < ... < x_{n} < b$, other with $a < x_{2} < x_{1} < ... < x_{n} < b$, and so on. I have $n!$ regions of this kind, but since the functin is symmetric, all the integrals give the same contribution. Is it? Can I really do this separation?

Comment: Yes. You are essentially doing a change of variables, in order to integrate over the unit cube. Look at the 2D example first, where in one you're integrating the region above $x_1 = x_2$, and in the other you're integrating the region under $x_1 = x_2$. Note that we require the measure to be "atomless", which it is for Lebesgue integral (but not necessarily in all applications of physics, like the Dirac measutre)